# reading xml file in java

Tags: java, xml

i want read XML file using Java ,but the structure of XML file is unknown or in other words the content of XML file is generated dynamically how to read each and every element along with attributes.

Answer (score 2):

[JDOM](http://www.jdom.org) can help you.

Answer (score 2):

DOM and SAX parsers are part of the JDK, and a bunch of other libraries are available. In general, you don't need to know the format in order to parse the document. You do need to know the format (or at least some of it) in order to extract data from the document, though.

Answer (score 0):

I use XML Pull Parser:

http://xmlpull.org/index.shtml

It is very fast and easy to use. You really do not know the exact structure of the XML file to be able to parse it - that is the reason why the XML format exists... It just needs to be in compliance with http://www.w3.org/XML/ specification.